# Mapping routes with static number in the middle

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

```
$route['9/(:num)/(:any)/1/(:num)'] = "web/organization/news/$1/$3";
$route['9/(:num)/(:any)/1'] = "web/organization/news/$1";

$route['9/(:num)/(:any)/2/(:num)'] = "web/organization/docs/$1/$3";
$route['9/(:num)/(:any)/2'] = "web/organization/docs/$1";
```

When paginating (1 record per page), the following url-s: http://www.mydomain.com/webapp/9/14/Name/1/2 and http://www.mydomain.com/webapp/9/14/Name/2/2 are giving me the same view.

First URL should give me the third page with news, but it gives me third page with documents.

I'm using Codeigniter 1.7.2

Comment: if i change 1 and 2 with some character or if i set route like this 9/1/(:num)/(:any)/(:num) everything works as expected.

Comment: please note that routes are order dependant and if one (first) is used second one is ignored. "Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones."

Comment: i know this. but in this case, the 4th segment of the route is different (1 or 2). So why CI maps "9/14/Name/1/2" to docs method, if 4th segment is '1' and it should be mapped to news method.

Comment: I dont know why you need this but I would go for creating controller that handles this or use `_remap()`, `controller/method/par1/par2/offset` messing with routes is never a good idea.